# Adding Back Terms to solve for nth term

Tags: sequences-and-series

Q: If the first term of a sequence is $3$, and each of the following terms is found by multiplying the preceding term by $2$, what is the units digit of the $32$nd term in the sequence?

My Attempt: I get a remainder of zero when I divide $32$ by $4$, so ignoring the first term of $3$, the fake-first-term is $6$. If i add back the first term the $32$nd term is $2$; i'm not correct, thee $32$nd term is actually $8$. What's my error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the answer is 4. Because the nth term is $3\cdot2^{n-1}$. And any power of two where $n\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ ends in an 8. And since the 32nd term is $3\cdot2^{32-1}$ and $31\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ the last digit is the same as the last digit of $3\cdot8$ which is 4.

Comment: If 3 is actually the zeroth term then we multiply by two to get 8.